# Android Jetpack Compose Documentation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to find the official Android Compose documentation, but I can't find it.

I'm looking for something like the [Flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/widgets-library.html).

What I need is to know the properties of the components and how to use them, something like the Flutter documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Jetpack Compose documentation can be found at https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose

The documentation for all the classes is [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/ui/classes) and you can find a list of packages [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/ui/packages).

Since you mention components and how to use them, the [functions in the material library](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary.html#top-level-functions-summary) are probably most relevant to you.  There's also a [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial) that demonstrates some basic usage.

Comment: The link to classes is broken but they are accessible within the individual packages.  Navigation is not too easy e.g. I searched for Box but the closest match was BoxScope, which I selected and then found a link to Box within that.